# regex in java to change an instance of occuring variables

Tags: java, regex

I want to regex a string of multiple of the same character and convert it to 1 character. For example if I have a `String a = "aaaaaaaaaab"` I want to replace it with `"ab"`.

Comment: why a regex? this is more suited to a simple iteration imho

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
a = a.replaceAll("(.)\\1+", "$1");
```

The `\1` maps to the first group (.).

Comment: This is the right answer, but it's Java, you'll need to double scape the \1, resulting 'a.replaceAll("(.)\\1+", "$1")'

Comment: Fantastic! I thought that I know regular expressions well. Now I understand that it was wrong...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for:

```
a=a.replaceAll("[a]+", "a");
```

This will replace all the occurrences of "a" with a single "a"